# How to close a parent fragment from child fragment in navigation component

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm creating an app that need to nested navigation graphs and a want to close a parent fragment from child fragment.

I can close a fragment by calling
`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();`
with this i can only close the current top fragment in back stack.

[image]

in this picture i want to close Fragment2 from Framgent3.

EDIT:

I'm opening Fragment2 with:
`Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_fragment1_to_fragment2);`

Fragment1:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        getView().findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.action_fragment1_to_fragment2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Fragment1 layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Framgent2:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void close () {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

in Fragment2 i have another graph, Fragment2 layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/child_graph_base"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/child_graph" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment3:

```
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getView().findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getParentFragment();
                Fragment2 fragment2 = (Fragment2) navHostFragment.getParentFragment();
                fragment2.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Fragment3 layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main Graph (MainActivity):
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="alistar.navigation.fragments.Fragment1"
        android:label="fragment1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment1" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment1_to_fragment2"
            app:destination="@id/fragment2" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="alistar.navigation.fragments.Fragment2"
        android:label="fragment2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment2" />
</navigation>
```

Child Graph (in Framgent2)

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/child_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment3">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment3"
        android:name="alistar.navigation.fragments.Fragment3"
        android:label="fragment3"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment3" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: You can use interface or [LocalBroadcastManager.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager) Also have a look [How to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

Comment: will you show your code? so we can have clear view .

Comment: @RumitPatel local broadcast manager is deprecated in androidx and replaced with LiveData

Comment: @ RumitPatel @EpicPandaForce why i should use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i solved the problem by calling `close()` method in the parent fragment (Fragment2) from Fragment3. i changed close method to this:

```
public void close () {
    Navigation.findNavController(getView()).popBackStack();
}
```

also i removed:

```
app:defaultNavHost="true"
```

from my child graph and worked OK!

Comment: How did you call Fragment 2 from Fragment 3? Can you share your approach?

Comment: @pratz9999 use getParentFragment() method.

Answer (score 0):

include the graph of (frag2,frag3) in frag1's graph using include

```
<include app:graph="@navigation/frag1_graph"/>
```

and then:

add an action to your fragment3 with appropriate Destination and popUpTo arguments

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/Fragment3"
    android:name="whatever"
    android:label="whatever"
    tools:layout="@layout/whatever" >
     <action
        android:id="@+id/action_Fragment3_to_Fragmen1"
        app:destination="@id/Fragment1"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
       app:popUpTo="@+id/Fragment1"
       app:popUpToInclusive="true" /> </fragment>
```

and then

```
findNavController(fragment).navigate(R.id.action_Fragment3_to_fragment1)
```

and then display fragment3 again. i think that's what you want right?

Comment: i'm using navigation component.

Comment: can't you just use the navigate functionality then?

Comment: Fragment3 is not in the Fragment1 graph.

Comment: why not add it to the graph? is there any reason for it? it is very simple if you add it to the graph.

Comment: because i have some view's in Fragment2 and i need them.

Comment: you can include frag2,frag3 graph in frag1's graph using include, then you can navigate the graph trivially

Comment: frag1 and frag2 are in the same graph, but frag3 graph is in frag2.

Comment: ok you need to post your xml, i am really confused by what your graph is